# You cannot run CocoaPods as root (Ionic) iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cocoapods

I am getting this error, when i am installing 'phonegap-plugin-push' i m getting the following error, i think i am having trouble installing pods.

Thanks in advance

Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push':undefined

Error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.1/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)

Usage:

```
$ pod COMMAND

  CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.
```

Commands:

```
+ cache      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache
+ env        Display pod environment
+ init       Generate a Podfile for the current directory
+ install    Install project dependencies according to versions from a
             Podfile.lock
+ ipc        Inter-process communication
+ lib        Develop pods
+ list       List pods
+ outdated   Show outdated project dependencies
+ repo       Manage spec-repositories
+ setup      Setup the CocoaPods environment
+ spec       Manage pod specs
+ update     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock
```

Options:

```
--silent     Show nothing
--version    Show the version of the tool
--verbose    Show more debugging information
--no-ansi    Show output without ANSI codes
--help       Show help banner of specified command
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.1.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

did you use install it with using sudo ?
that's why it gave you error. you can directly install with without using sudo. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this issue, there was folder rights issue